# Multiple plots with error bars

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot two graphs with error bars from an external file. The data file contains the columns  x, y1, y1+, y1-, y2, y2+, y2-, where y1+ etc. are the error bars for the corresponding y-values. Now I am somehow unable to tell Latex to which y (1 or 2) it should add the error bars. I end up with graph y1 having in total 4 error bars (y1+, y1-, y2+, y2-) and y2 having none.

This is the code that I tried:

```
\documentclass[article]{standalone}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat = newest}  % loads newest improved settings

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[scale only axis, xlabel = x, xmin = -1, xmax = 1, ylabel = y,  ymax = 1.3e19, ymin = 0, ytick pos=left]


\addplot[clip marker paths=true,color = blue,mark = none,thick,]
 table [y index = 1] {1bar_density_data.txt};

\addplot+[only marks, blue, mark=*, mark options={blue}, error bars/.cd,y dir=plus,  y explicit] table [y error index=2]{1bar_density_data.txt};
\addplot+[blue, only marks, mark=*, mark options={blue}, error bars/.cd,y dir=minus,  y explicit] table [y error index=3]{1bar_density_data.txt};


\addplot[clip marker paths=true, color = green, mark = none,]
 table [y index = 4] {1bar_density_data.txt};

\addplot+[only marks, green, mark=*, mark options={green}, error bars/.cd,y dir=plus,  y explicit] table [y error index=5]{1bar_density_data.txt};
\addplot+[green, only marks, mark=*, mark options={green}, error bars/.cd,y dir=minus,  y explicit] table [y error index=6]{1bar_density_data.txt};

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

With this result[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post an example of the data file you're using? Most likely, you should rename the columns in which you store the error bars to something more descriptive, or use the index notation

Comment: You can find the data for the above example here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/62b1tpenwj6se1g/AAD56G7PJvwTWSo7bCgpIWWva?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have not specified which `y` value you want to plot with the error bars, so the default value of `y index=1` is used for both plots, even though the error bars are properly specified. The following MWE gives me two sets of `y` data with two error bars each. Note that I have

1. Removed `\usepackage{tikz}` because `pgfplots` already does this
2. Removed the (unused?) `article` option to `standalone`
3. Added explicit `x index` options to the `clip marker paths` plots
4. Removed the `+` from the `\addplot` specification because you're setting most of the relevant options anyways

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.11, % loads newest improved settings
    width=9.5cm,
    height=5cm,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale only axis,
xlabel = y-Position (mm),
xmin = -1,
xmax = 1,
ylabel = Normalized Electron Density (a.u.),
ymax = 1.0e19,
ymin = 0,
ytick pos=left
]
\addplot[clip marker paths=true,color = blue,mark = none,thick,] table [x index=0, y index=1] {1bar_density_data.txt};
\addplot[only marks, blue, mark=*, mark options={blue}, error bars/.cd,y dir=plus,  y explicit] table [x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2]{1bar_density_data.txt};
\addplot[blue, only marks, mark=*, mark options={blue}, error bars/.cd,y dir=minus,  y explicit] table [x index=0, y index=1, y error index=3]{1bar_density_data.txt};
\addplot[clip marker paths=true, color = green, mark = none,] table [x index=0, y index=4] {1bar_density_data.txt};
\addplot[only marks, green, mark=*, mark options={green}, error bars/.cd,y dir=plus,  y explicit] table [x index=0, y index=4, y error index=5]{1bar_density_data.txt};
\addplot[green, only marks, mark=*, mark options={green}, error bars/.cd,y dir=minus,  y explicit] table [x index=0, y index=4, y error index=6]{1bar_density_data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that was exactly the option I probably overlooked all the time. Thanks also for cleaning up my code a bit!